# Laravel 5.6. JSONb column. Count array

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, jsonb, laravel-5.6

I'm using JSONb columns of the PostgreSQL.

I have such an array in my `data` column

```
{
    myKey: []
}
```

How can I check through Laravel, if this array is empty or not?

Something like

```
MyModel::where('data->myKey'...)
```

Comment: You should check this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html . json_array_length might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a raw statement:

```php
MyModel::whereRaw("json_array_length((data->'myKey')::json) > 0")
```

In Laravel 5.7.2 you can use `whereJsonLength()`:

```php
MyModel::whereJsonLength('data->myKey', '>', 0)
```