# Laravel eloquent query to get records with array with specified length

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent, where-clause

It seems like this should be pretty simple to find the answer to but apparently not for me.
I need to query a count of records where the field called `bullets` contains an array with a length of 5. Here is what I currently have but it's checking for character length of the field itself(I believe), not of an array. Can anyone help me out please?

```
$vcount = Variation::where('user_id', user_id)->whereRaw('LENGTH(bullets) = 5')->count();
```

Comment: Try using the `JSON_LENGTH` sql function to get the number of elements in the array.

Comment: @pmcpimentel Thanks for the suggestion but this didn't work for me (Or maybe my syntax was wrong). I ended up finding whereJsonLength() in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820839/laravel-5-6-jsonb-column-count-array
Will post the answer below

Answer (score 1):

thanks to this thread [Laravel 5.6. JSONb column. Count array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50820839/laravel-5-6-jsonb-column-count-array)

I found whereJsonLength() that worked for my use case:

```
$vcount = Variation::where('user_id', user_id)->whereJsonLength('bullets', '=', 5)->count();
```